# Send a message directly from a thread to an object without using the main form

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm using a 3rd party library that uses a lot of threads.

I've just started using messages to communicate back to the main thread from a thread. It's all working, but using SendMessage the way I describe below seems cumbersome because *the main form has to dispatch all the messages.* Is there a way to send a message directly to a frame or object, without depending on the main form?

At program startup:

```
 MyMessageNumber1 :=  RegisterWindowMessage('MyUniqueID1');
 MyMessageNumber2 :=  RegisterWindowMessage('MyUniqueID2');
```

When sending a message without any data, I do:

```
 SendMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle,  MyMessageNumber1)
```

My main form has this:

```
procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
if (Message.Msg = MyMessageNumber1)
  ... call a frame or other object's method that handles this particular message
else if (Message.Msg = MyMessageNumber2) then
  ... call another ....
else
  inherited;
```

In summary: the above WndProc has to know far more than I'd prefer about all the messages and who to dispatch them to.

How can I send a message directly from a thread in a way that any object can receive it?

All of these messages have no data associated with them. (We'll get to that some other day!) :-)

TIA

Comment: I find it difficult to accept the notion that WndProc could ever know too much about messages. Handling messages is WndProc's **job**.

Comment: #Rob Kennedy - But if the WndProc is in the main form (as I thought was necessary, thus this question)  then the main form would have to know about all sorts of details of low level code so it could dispatch messages to them. Why should the main form need to know any internal details of some low-level code when, as Mason points out,  the low-level code can explicitly catch the message??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other forms and frames have handles as well, and you can define message-handling methods on them, then post the message directly to the form or frame.  (Or control, for that matter, if you're building your own custom controls.)

See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_a_New_Message-handling_Method for an overview on setting up message-handling methods.

Comment: Be careful with this.  The TWinControl.Handle property is NOT thread-safe.  If a control's HWND is busy being recreated at the time the message is being sent, reading the control's Handle property from inside the thread can have serious consequences.  Best to use AllocateHWND() to set asside a dedicated HWND instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - In what context is a control's HWND busy being recreated?  If, for example, my control is part of an app's main form that or frame on the main form, does the HWND ever get recreated after the program is running?

Comment: Yes, it can.  TWinControl has a public RecreateWnd() method.  Many VCL property setters call RecreateWnd() internally when a new property value needs to be applied to an existing HWND.  Rather than use SetWindowLong() (which would be more efficient and not require re-creating the HWND), most VCL controls that manipulate HWND attributes will simply call RecreateWnd() and then override CreateWnd() to apply the current property values to each HWND that gets created during the control's lifetime.

Comment: The TWinControl.Handle getter is not thread-safe because if a control is currently in the process of (re)creating its HWND at the same time that the thread accesses the control's Handle property, the main thread can potentially lose ownership of an HWND and leak it, and the thread can gain ownership of a separate HWND (rendering the control useless). An HWND is owned by the thread context that allocates it, and only that thread context can receive messages for that HWND.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You can use AllocateHWND to allocate a window handle in any object. This handle can be used to send messages to.

But you problem may lie in the SendMessage. If you use PostMessage instead of SendMessage, the call will return immediately. PostMessage does not wait for a message to be handled. So if you don't need the message result, and you don't need to send references to thread-data, you can just use PostMessage.

Comment: I see that someone downvoted this response. That may be because you wouldn't need to create a handle for a Frame or other WinControl that already has a handle. However, if you want *any object* to be able to receive the message, you will need to provide that object with a handle.

Comment: And PostMessage is still more efficient for interthreaded communication if you don't need to send data. :)

Comment: That goes for controls as well. TTimer is a great example of a non-windowed control that uses AllocateWND to create a window for receiving timer messages.

Comment: +1 for "if you want any object to be able to receive the message, you will need to provide that object with a handle".